# Accessing concrete attribute in Java generic function

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Java generics. I have written one function like following:

```
  public class C<T extends MyClass> implements MyInterface<T>{
      public void f(T obj){
         ...
         obj.getName()
      }
   }
```

Above function `f` is called for two types of objects `MySubClass1` and `MySubClass2`. `MySubClass1` and `MySubClass2` are two concreter classes inherited from abstract class `MyClass` and `name` is an attribute of `MySubClass2`.

When f is called with object of `MySubClass2` , I would like to access name like above. I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code (missing semicolon). You could always cast `obj` to `MySubClass2`, but this is bad design. A [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) might help. This looks like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Care to elaborate what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Aominè Why do you need an MCVE here?

Answer (score 5):

> ...and name is an attribute of MySubClass2

Then your method can't rely on it being there, since `obj` can be **anything** deriving from `MyClass`.

This suggests your design should change such that either you have separate methods or you move name to `MyClass`.

You *could* do it with an `instanceof` check and a cast:

```
if (obj instanceof MySubClass2) {
    String name = ((MySubClass2)obj).getName();
}
```

...but nine times out of ten, using `instanceof` should make you step back and reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

In a generic method that takes `T` constrained to `MyClass` only methods of `MyClass` are available. Since `getName` is implemented only in `MySubClass2`, you cannot access `getName` without a cast to `MySubClass2`, which goes contrary to the point of making your `f()` method generic in the first place.

You can pass a `Function` object that pulls `name` from `T` to `f()`, like this:

```
public void f(T obj, Function<T,String> getName){
    ...
    String name = getName.apply(obj);
}
```

The caller would invoke `f()` like this:

```
MySubClass2 s2 = new MySubClass2();
MyInterface<MySubClass2> c = new C<>();
c.f(s2, MySubClass2::getName);
```

Note that this technique lets you call `f` on `MySubClass1` objects, as long as you provide *some* way of getting a name:

```
MySubClass1 s1 = new MySubClass1();
MyInterface<MySubClass1> c = new C<>();
c.f(s1, x -> "<no-name>");
```

Comment: This solution only moves the problem up one level. What if the calling side only has a `MyClass`-reference to begin with (although it might contain a `MySubClass2`)?

Comment: @Turing85 This problem is "baked into" the task of discriminating among subclassed of `MyClass` in a generic call. This ugliness has to show up in *some* place; I prefer the calling site to the method itself; T.J. showed the other alternative.